# Springboot: Modificar query search Mongo o filtrar el resutlado

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Quiero hacer algo tan sencillo como, haciendo uso del método search en MongoRepository, recuperar todos los usuarios de una colección únicamente si su nombre **no empieza por #**.

Entiendo que existen 2 opciones:

1. Modificar el método:

   @Query("{$or:[{null:?0}, {grupos:{$in:[?0]}}]}")
   Page search(String grupo, Pageable pageable);
2. O bien, recuperar todos los Usuarios pero luego filtrar la lista con alguna expresión .stream. Algo así como: usuarios.getContent().stream().forEach(XXXXX)

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias de antemano!
Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución, tenía que añadir en la etiqueta @Query la nueva condición $regex ->

```
@Query("{$and:[ {nombre:{'$regex' : '^((?!#).)*$', '$options' : 'i'}}, {$or:[{null:?0}, {grupos:{$in:[?0]}}]}]}")
    Page<Usuario> search(String grupo, Pageable pageable);
```